# Splide Thumbnail Carousel with multiple images in main carousel?

Tags: carousel, slide

when using Splide you can build a thumbnail and main carousel and link them together - see here: https://kralinator.com/hosted/bouche-test/portfolio-fashion.php

I would like the main carousel to display 3 images, much like you can do with a standard carousel (perPage: 3), but that doesn't seem to work with two linked carousels like this.

Presently it just displays one

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Tried using perPage but didn't work - just pushed the main image to ht left (as if making space for the other two)